# Replacing images on a page/website that match a pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I need help with some JS/jquery (jquery preferred) that can replace all images on a site that match a specific pattern.  On the page we have images that look like:

```
img src="http://a248.e.akamai.net/a/262/9086/10h/origin-d9.scene7.com/is/image/default/**A34567_v1**?wid=570&hei=413&fmt=jpeg&qlt=92,0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=1.1,0.5,1,0"
```

If the image src contains the "_v1" I would like to change just that character string to "_v2".  Using the example above the final result would be:

```
img src="http://a248.e.akamai.net/a/262/9086/10h/origin-d9.scene7.com/is/image/default/**A34567_v2**?wid=570&hei=413&fmt=jpeg&qlt=92,0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=1.1,0.5,1,0"
```

This could happen multiple times on a page.  Can anyone assist?

Thanks!

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide multiple examples, I cannot tell what pattern you will want to use. However, I created a simplified version with regular expressions to point you in the right way:

Consider this HTML: You want to change all old to new.

```
<img src="/old_a.png" />
<img src="/new_b.png" />
<img src="/old_c.png" />
```

You would loop through all img tags using jQuery like this:

```
$("img").each(function(i, element){
    var pattern = /[old]/; //A regular expression that you'll have to modify to your needs
    var src = $(element).attr("src");
    if(pattern.test(src))
        $(element).attr("src", src.replace("old", "new"));
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R9Eah/)

Basicly what this does is that it applies a regular expression to each image element. You'll have to create that regular expression yourself, however.

Comment: The regex you might want to use could be `/default/[*A-Z0-9]*_v1` depending on how the other images look.

Comment: After re-reading your question might actually just skip the regex since all you wanted to do is a simple replace

Answer (score 0):

This might do it:

```
$(function(){

    $('img').each(function(index, img){
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('_v1**', '_v2**'));
    });

});
```